# Warning: Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

When I run the following R shiny app, I get the message "**Warning: Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector**," and the app stops (just the error message appears on the shiny page). As a newbie in R shiny, I have no idea what went wrong. Can anyone help me tackle this problem?

The app is working properly when I get the codes for getting and preprocessing data outside UI (i.e., before UI). So, there would be no error of this kind if I can get user_id passed by html/javascript codes (this R shiny app is embedded in iframe in HTML) outside/before UI. Is this possible?

```
### load dependenices
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
coul <- brewer.pal(5, "Set2")

### connect to database
tryCatch({
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  print("Connecting to Database…")
  connec <- dbConnect(drv,
                    dbname = "postgres",
                    host = "localhost",
                    port = "5432",
                    user = "postgres",
                    password = "postgres")
  print("Database Connected!"
)},
  error=function(cond) {
  print("Unable to connect to Database.")
})

### define ui logic to display a bar chart dashboard
ui <- fluidPage(  
# provide a sample id for demonstration
user_id=1111111
# get and preprocess data
query <- paste0("SELECT group_level, your_course, your_institution, peer_institutions, all_institutions
            FROM data_by_learning_objective
            WHERE user_id ='",user_id,"'"),
data_by_lo <- dbGetQuery(connec, query),
data_by_lo <- data_by_lo %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = 'group_level')
# give the page a title
titlePanel("Average Scores by Learning Objective"),
# Generate a row with a sidebar:
sidebarLayout(
  # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("lo", "Group Level:", 
                choices=colnames(data_by_lo)),
    hr(),
    helpText("Assessment Data from Cell Collective.")
    ),
  # Create a spot for the barplot
  mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scorePlot")  
  )
 )
)

### Define server logic required to display a bar chart dashboard
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$scorePlot <- renderPlot({
  # Render a barplot
  x <- barplot(data_by_lo[, input$lo]*100, 
          main=input$lo,
          ylab="Average Score (%)",
          xlab="Learning Objective",
          col=coul)
  y <- as.matrix(data_by_lo[, input$lo])
  text(x,y+20,labels=as.character(round(y*100),2))
  })
}

### Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello urban119, your code is neither reproducible nor sintactically valid. In particular,  the trycatch block could not be located here.   UI defines user interface elements. Also in the server, renderPlot box must return a plot (i.e. barplot) while your re returning `text`

Comment: @Ric Villalba: How can I attach a dataset to make the code reproducible? I've moved the trycatch block outside/before UI. The app works well, returning a barplot, when I put the code for getting and preprocessing data outside/before UI (the text is to add a label (score) to each plot). I've put the code for getting the data inside UI because I need to add includeHtml() and includeScript() to get user_id passed from outside the app. If there is a way to put codes to get user_id outside/before UI, that will resolve this issue.